# How to get the percentage of records with valid date using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table say Product

```
Id  ProductName DueDate
---------------------------
1   A           9999-12-31
2   B           9999-12-31
3   C           9999-12-31   
4   D           2017-08-10  
and so on
```

I have to calculate if the percentage of rows with valid due date (ignore 9999-12-31) is greater than 60% or not. Also get all the ids from the table which has valid date.

I have tried to use the SUM and case condition to get the percentage. How can I get the ID as well. I have tried with Sub queries. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Please share the query you have used up until now and describe what is not working as expected. See also [ask] a good question and how to include a  [mcve].

Comment: What would your desired results look like given this sample data? I don't understand how would have a percentage AND the id in the same output. I also don't understand what "Valid due date" means. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to assist in this. Note that you could also use `partition by` within the `over clause` (e.g. for calculations by product) if that is needed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da0da/5)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Id] int, [ProductName] varchar(1), [DueDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Id], [ProductName], [DueDate])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'B', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'C', '9999-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (5, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (6, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (7, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (8, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (9, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (10, 'D', '2017-08-10 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        *
        , case when DueDate <> '99991231' then 1 else 0 end as is_valid
        , (count(case when DueDate <> '99991231' then DueDate end) over() * 1.0)
          / count(*) over() as pct
    from table1
    ) d
where is_valid = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da0da/5/0)**:

```
| Id | ProductName |              DueDate | is_valid | pct |
|----|-------------|----------------------|----------|-----|
|  4 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
|  5 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
|  6 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
|  7 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
|  8 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
|  9 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
| 10 |           D | 2017-08-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 0.7 |
```